# Groovy script to get Jenkins pipeline's script path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I want to run a script in Jenkins Script Console to retrieve **scriptPath** parameter of all jobs/pipelines configured in Jenkins. I found the way to get names of the pipelines but I want **scriptPath** parameters of each pipeline.

Any leads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All pipeline jobs are instances of `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob` and can be found using the `Jenkins.instance.getAllItems` function.
Once found, each job contains an attribute of the `FlowDefinition` class whcih is accessible via the `getDefinition()` method. There are two types of definition for pipelines:

1. `CpsFlowDefinition` - for pipelines which define an inline script (not SCM), the script is accessible via the `getScript()` method.
2. `CpsScmFlowDefinition` - for pipelines which define an SCM script, the script is accessible via the `getScriptPath()` method.

So to achieve what you want you can go over relevant jobs and extract the relevant attribute:

```groovy
def pipelineJobs =Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)
def scmJobs = pipelineJobs.findAll { it.definition =~ 'CpsScmFlowDefinition'}

scmJobs.each {
    println "Pipeline Name: ${it.name}"
    println "SCM Script Path: ${it.definition.scriptPath}"
}
```

If **all your jobs** are SCM pipelines you can use the following single liner:

```groovy
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)*.definition.scriptPath
```

For a single specific job you can use:

```groovy
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("<PIPELINE_NAME>").definition.scriptPath // or just script for inline definition
```